# If there are two processors in one system, could the second processor be controlled if it has a different architecture?

Tags: x86, arm, 64-bit, cpu-architecture, arm64

Say I had a computer that had 2 processors, one used x64, and the other used ARM. Would a x64 Linux Kernel be able to control the second (ARM) processor?

Comment: Define "control".

Comment: Even without considering things like AMD's Secure Processor, your x64 machine is probably already controlling plenty of ARM processors - in your disk drive, your network chip, etc. Or are you specifically asking about shared memory communication rather than things on the other end of dedicated interfaces? (in which case, since you mention Linux, have a look into the remoteproc framework)

Comment: By control, I mean send instructions to the processor. I didn't think this was necessary to say, but in my case, I would want to know if Kali Linux could control the ARM processor in the new macbooks(T1?) to control the touch bar.

Comment: Define "send instructions". In the sense of "send it the commands it expects through whatever interface it's presented on to make it do the stuff its firmware is designed to do", then obviously that's possible, because macOS does it. Conceptually it's no different from, say, the triple-core ARM CPU in modern Samsung SSDs in that respect. If you mean "replace the entire firmware with something which lets you execute arbitrary code", consider how many Apple products allow you to do that for even the main application processor, let alone peripheral processors.

Comment: I'm not sure how the touch bar works so I'm not sure which one it is, but I am guessing it would have to be the second one since Kali does not have drivers for the touch bar. I know that Apple doesn't do it by default, but since the OS might be able to discover the extra CPU, it might be able to send low-level processor instructions, not instructions through Apple's interface.

Comment: There has to be some degree of control for communication, but I highly doubt Apple would leave such a backdoor open at the user or even OS level. For starters, it would mean that a virus could easily read out your secured data. There may be security holes (everything has), but you'll probably have to wait for someone to expose them

Comment: This could maybe be answerable if you interpret it as asking if an SMP system with ARM + x86 cores could be built.  (well, not actually symmetric).  But cache-coherent ARM + x86.  And could one master CPU initiate bootup of dormant other CPUs, like the boot core does for other cores in a normal SMP.  (Instead of them having to boot separately, like the microcontrollers in HDs and stuff.)

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but x86 SMP systems have IPIs (Inter-Processor Interrupts) that get very infrequent use when writing something to shared memory and waiting for the other core(s) to read it isn't what you want.  (e.g. to implement [the Linux `membarrier(2)` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/membarrier.2.html)).  Does ARM have anything like that, @Notlikethat?  Assuming that someone built an ARM CPU that could share a bus with an Intel or AMD x86, or share a chip even, any idea if the semantics of IPIs are compatible enough to allow one CPU to boot the other?

Comment: @Peter Yes, SMP ARM systems have IPIs (life would be pretty hard without), but wiring a GIC directly to an APIC would be more trouble than it's worth, and it's not like you could run a single SMP OS instance across both sets of CPUs anyway, so there'd be no point. Honestly, I don't know why the tech news has picked up on this aspect of the Apple thing. The remote management chips in servers [are often](http://www.aspeedtech.com/products.php?fPath=20&rId=200) a complete ARM system running Linux, appearing as a peripheral to the host machine - there's nothing new or clever about it.

Comment: I just saw the OP's comment about what inspired the question.  Totally agree that's not interesting; one of the I used to admin had a IPMI lights-out-manage boards like that in every node.  I'm not convinced it's impossible to run a single OS image across both sets of CPUs, though.  There are major hurdles, but I think it's possible *in theory*.  I'm not suggesting it would be worth anyone's time to do this, even if a cache-coherent hybrid x86+ARM existed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think (with a large amount of software engineering busywork, but no insurmountable obstacles that I can see) you could run a single ARM + x86 Linux kernel across a hypothetical cache-coherent machine with a mix of ARM + x86 cores, for example.

These don't exist; multiple CPUs of different architectures in the same system are always doing different jobs, and hooked up to different RAM, and communicate over some bus, like SATA or PCIe.  **I'm answering this aspect of the question because it's the only one that's interesting / non-trivial.**

There would be one shared pool of memory shared by the whole system, so memory would essentially be competitively shared between ARM and x86 processes, instead of having to statically partition it.  The pagecache (aka disk cache) would also be shared, along with other caches (like VFS directory entries / inodes).

Most intra-CPU interaction in the kernel is just done by writing to memory and waiting for kernel code on another core to notice it.  (e.g. if a process starts a new thread and keeps running, the kernel just puts that new task in the task list where another core that's running the scheduler will notice it.  Starting a new thread doesn't cause the current core to look for a core for the thread to run on, instead cores look at the task list and pick something to do next.)

So as long as cache-coherent shared-memory works correctly, and x86 and ARM processes can synchronize with each other with memory barriers and so on, I don't see why it wouldn't be possible in theory.

Drivers already have to work on SMP systems, so as long as locking works properly to exclude other threads (regardless of whether they're ARM or x86), things should work.

You'd need:

- Function pointers in the kernel.  Every kernel function pointer needs to have an x86 and an ARM version.  Linux makes heavy use of function pointers to dispatch to the right driver for e.g. a filesystem.  Crap, I just thought of this one after writing most of the rest of the answer, and it may be a showstopper.  I could imagine using a C++ compiler to compile the kernel, so you could replace function-pointers in every struct with a template wrapper that had room for two pointers, and dereferencing take the right pointer for the architecture.  But taking the address of a function to store a function pointer into a struct means ARM code needs to know what the right x86 pointer to assign is, and vice-versa.

  Or *maybe* if you're insane, you could set up the memory mapping, and binary layout, so x86 cores see the x86 version of a function at the same virtual address that ARM cores see the ARM version of that function.  You only need this for functions that have their addresses taken, but it sounds insane and like it would take a lot of fiddling to get the linker to leave enough padding for this to be possible given that different architectures will have different machine-code sizes for the same function.

  With a less flexible kernel that didn't put so many function-pointers into ops structs for different filesystems, this would be easier.

  Maybe you could have ARM and x86 versions of each ops struct, and writers would have to set both, but readers would only read the one they want.  They're not set frequently, mostly when a new FS is mounted, or a new device plugged in, I think.
- All the struct layouts must be compatible (potentially a ton of work making that happen, or maybe just get some compiler help by tweaking the ABI).
- The scheduler needs to know that it should only run ARM processes on ARM cores, and x86 processes on x86 cores.
- The system needs to be able to boot somehow, and get two kernel images built from the same source loaded into memory.  This is going to be the major challenge, because there are probably assumptions about which physical / virtual addresses the kernel lives in.  The boot process has to load two copies of the kernel code, but only one copy of read-only data and static non-constant data.  (And both pieces of code have to have the right addresses for all of these things).
- Memory management: ARM and x86 use different page-table formats.  An x86 process reading the `/proc/<pid>/maps` of an ARM process will probably cause the kernel to look at the page tables for a process of the other architecture.  (Or maybe Linux keeps this info in a mapping start/length format as well as in the actual page tables.)  Still, I could imagine this being an issue.

  The kernel managing the system-wide pool of memory might also be tricky, if there are assumptions about where the kernel's code is located that are violated by having two different versions loaded.
- Threads: If you want to use all x86 + ARM cores in the system for a shared-memory task, you'll have to do it with two processes that map some shared memory.  The alternative is to write a new system call that lets an x86 process start an ARM thread, the same way the kernel works, but *this* is where it would probably take a lot of work.  This is definitely where the separate-page-table-formats problem would bite, because all threads in a process normally share the same page table.
- **Memory barrier macros and so on have to be implemented in a way that synchronizes with code running on cores of the other architecture.**  Presumably the x86 cores would still obey the x86 memory model, where stores become globally visible in program order, etc. etc.  (See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for links to more about the x86 memory model).

  Similarly the ARM cores would obey the usual ARM memory model, so their loads could become globally visible out of order, if they don't use barriers or acquire-loads, regardless of whether the core that produced the data was ARM or x86.

  Memory-ordering is all about the order of a core's own operations on its private L1 cache (which is coherent with all other data caches in the system).  Store buffers allow invisible reordering, but once something is written to L1 cache, it's globally visible, no matter who's reading it.  This is what it means for caches to be coherent.

  **So the questions is whether any synchronization idioms depend on assumptions about the other thread, which might not be true if it's using a different memory model.**  e.g. a lock taken by an ARM core needs to exclude x86 threads from the critical section, and vice-versa.  I think this should mostly work, but it's the one area I've thought of so far where I'm not sure.  It might require tweaks to some Linux inline-asm macros.  Linux abstracts a LOT of this for use by arch-independent parts of the kernel, so it's pretty well set up for making `smp_wmb()` (write memory barrier) stronger if needed, for example.

Comment: So it's not really worth anyone's time.

Comment: _"So as long as cache-coherent shared-memory works correctly..."_ - hehe... Given the cache architectures, memory ordering models, etc., let alone the physical details like the actual coherency signalling protocols, to get to that point you'd basically have to design one or both CPU microarchitectures from scratch for this specific purpose. At that point, if you really need to run some ARM code it might be more realistic to just emulate it on some more x86 cores. An interesting thought, though, is if a system with Transmeta-style CPUs could run different translation layers between cores...

Comment: @GabrielSouthern Interesting! Funnily enough, if you take x86 out of the picture to imagine just the Thumb/Alpha ISA mix, then look at ARMv8-A and squint a bit...